# Average of Difference in SQL Server DateTime column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a data entry form that anybody must fill up 3 forms. I log the entry time for form 1, form 2, form 3. Now I want to know what is the average of time to fill up the forms for all people. How can I do that?

Comment: We can't tell from your data how long it took to fill the form, please be more precise about your problem.

Comment: I said **LIKE**,and I have not 3 people...and I want a script or a guide

Comment: What does your schema look like? Do you have a row for each log entry (e.g. you insert a new row for each form), or do you have a single row with a column for each form? Can you show the CREATE TABLE statement?

Comment: In what way do you log time for the forms? Is it with two columns, like `StartTime` & `EndTime`, or do you calculate the actual elapsed time and store it as one column, like `ElapsedTime`? Please, like @Aaron Bertrand said, do show us the CREATE TABLE statement (edit your post, please). That may answer many other questions of ours.

Comment: And do you want to include in the average for form 1 the time taken even for users who are still working on form 2 or have abandoned altogether? Are the averages correlated to the user or do you just want overall average time for everyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100% guesswork based on extremely vague requirements.

```
DECLARE @x TABLE
(
    UserID    INT,
    FormID    TINYINT,
    StartTime DATETIME,
    EndTime   DATETIME
);

INSERT @x VALUES

-- a user who has completed all three forms
    (1,1,'20110820 04:25:01','20110820 04:33:07'),
    (1,2,'20110820 04:34:05','20110820 04:38:33'),
    (1,3,'20110820 04:39:02','20110820 04:47:55'),

-- a user who has completed two forms
    (2,1,'20110820 04:25:54','20110820 04:29:32'),
    (2,2,'20110820 04:30:55','20110820 04:34:27'),

-- the same user who has completed 1.5 forms
    (2,1,'20110820 04:35:23','20110820 04:37:15'),
    (2,2,'20110820 04:38:34',NULL),

-- the same user who has completed all three forms
    (2,1,'20110820 04:45:12','20110820 04:49:07'),
    (2,2,'20110820 04:50:26','20110820 04:55:31'),
    (2,3,'20110820 04:56:41','20110820 05:01:23'),

-- a slow user who has completed all three forms
    (3,1,'20110820 05:25:04','20110820 05:43:07'),
    (3,2,'20110820 05:44:09','20110820 05:55:21'),
    (3,3,'20110820 05:59:41','20110820 06:24:23');
```

Here are some typical aggregations that I'm guessing might hit the one you're looking for:

```
SELECT -- avg by form regardless of user
    FormID, 
    completed_forms = COUNT(*), 
    average = AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, StartTime, EndTime))
FROM @x GROUP BY FormID;

SELECT -- avg by form and user
    UserID,
    FormID, 
    completed_forms = COUNT(*),
    [seconds] = AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, StartTime, EndTime))
FROM @x GROUP BY UserID, FormID;

SELECT -- avg by user regardless of form
    UserID,
    completed_forms = COUNT(*),
    [seconds] = AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, StartTime, EndTime))
FROM @x GROUP BY UserID;

-- if you want hh:mm:ss format and the form never takes > 24 hours to complete,
-- you can do this kind of thing to any of the above queries:

;WITH x(FormID, completed_forms, average) AS
(
    SELECT
        FormID,
        COUNT(*),
        AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, StartTime, EndTime))
    FROM @x GROUP BY FormID
)
SELECT 
    FormID, 
    completed_forms,
    [hh:mm:ss] = CONVERT(CHAR(8), (CONVERT(TIME(0), DATEADD(SECOND, average, '19000101'))))
FROM x;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok As i have understand you question.  say you are putting all three form data into database at the last when user clicks on the finish button. Follow below steps to achive your goal.

1. When the First Navigation or open on your wizard hold the Wizard start time.
2. let user finish their wizard and when he clicks on the finish button
   hold the finish time in memory

Condition's

1. if user don't finish there wizard then clear memroy  releted to this
   wizard.

Example :
 user have started wizard at 6:00:45 PM and finish it at 6:12:15 PM so to calculate this time between this use datediff function of SQL

use below lines as per your requirement

SELECT DATEDIFF(hour, @StartTime, @EndTime);
Return hours taken for wizard fillup

SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, @StartTime,@EndTime);
Return Minutes taken for wizard fillup

SELECT DATEDIFF(second, @StartTime, @EndTime);
Return Seconds taken for wizard fillup

SELECT DATEDIFF(millisecond,@StartTime, @EndTime);
Return Milliseconds taken for wizard fillup

Comment: Pretty sure Nima wants to measure each form individually, not the time for the whole process.